# Let D denote a point on base AB, and let E denote a point on leg BC of an isosceles triangle ABC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The triangles ABC, CDE, and BDE are all isosceles, and triangle BDE is similar to triangle ABC. Determine the angles of each triangle.

Since ABC and BDE triangles are similar, their angles have to be the same.

Comment: From what I understand of the description of the situation, there isn't enough information to determine the angles uniquely. However, you do have D is the midpoint of AB, E is the midpoint of CB, AC is parallel to DE and CD is perpendicular to AB. But you can make CD as long as you like for a given AB

Comment: You cannot make CD as long as you want for a given AB, as ABC and BDE triangle must be similar.